# Session Management on Identity Server 4

Tags: identityserver4

I've come across an article based on Identity Server V2

https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/dotnet/asp-net/introducing-single-sign-on-to-an-existing-asp-net-mvc-application/

On the section on "Sessions and sliding expiration"

it has 2 options 
-Sliding expiration “per application”
-Sliding expiration “per Identity Provider”
(details of each are on the article)

Need to know if these are still supported on Identity Server 4 as there is no specific documentation related to session management.